# Simplex 3D noise animation halts on mobile

Tags: webgl, perlin-noise, mobile-chrome, simplex-noise

I'm using [Stefan Gustavson's GLSL impl.](https://github.com/stegu/webgl-noise/blob/master/src/noise3D.glsl) of Simplex noise and animating it using WebGL. Works just fine on desktop, but on my Android device, both Chrome and Firefox, the animation always halts after a fixed period. There's no error/warning, the scripts and WebGL program continue running.
Same thing happens with the classic Perlin noise impl.
You can see a demo here: https://wix.github.io/kampos
Code is here: https://github.com/wix/kampos/blob/master/index.html
Turbulence impl. is here: https://github.com/wix/kampos/blob/master/src/effects/turbulence.js

Comment: Your shader multiplies `u_time` by `0.0001`.  What happens if you move this out of GLSL and into JavaScript?

Comment: change `precision mediump float;` to `precision highp float;`

Comment: @prideout this simply stretches time by a factor, so the animation speed is reasonable. But will try just for the sake of it (:

Comment: @gman I was positively sure I tried that, <face-palm>, but apparently not, that did the trick, thanks!
Another q, should I hard-code it to highp? Or is there a perf concern to keep it configurable?

Comment: From my experience you pretty much always want `highp`. On desktop precision qualifiers have no effect to begin with and on mobile anything but `highp` makes your life a lot harder across the fragmented device landscape without providing a reasonable performance benefit to justify the trouble.

Comment: In 2019 you probably want to start with `highp` and worry about perf later. Back in 2011 when WebGL shipped there were lots of phones that didn't support `highp` (it's an optional feature) but in 2019 most phones support highp. For example all iPhones since 2013 support highp. There is a perf difference but at least your code will work. Fixing your code to work in mediump is usually not trivial.

Comment: Thanks guys, @gman, @LJᛃ! If you think this information is valuable, please add an answer and I'll accept. Otherwise please we can probably delete it.